# How to fix Aiogram custom text filter?

Tags: api, telegram, aiogram

Here is the code(sorry, i'm newbie):

aiogram filter(he must answer for specific message):

```py
class Text(BaseFilter):
    string: str

    async def __call__(self, message:Message) -> bool:
        return message.text == self.string
```

Then I try to use it in my bot.

```py
async def start():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO
    )
    bots = Bot(token)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.message.register(register_echo, Text(string='Hello'))
```

But it's wrong:

> Text() takes no arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```python
class Text(BaseFilter):
    string: str

    def __init__(self, string: str) -> None:
        self.string = string

    async def __call__(self, message:Message) -> bool:
        return message.text == self.string
```